# Issue setting Intent View in client.getintent - dialogflow

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

I am having issues in setting the IntentView value in `"client.getintent"` function while trying to access the trainingphrases in C# dialogflow

```
 var client = IntentsClient.Create();
            var intentid = getid(intent);

            string intentname = "projects/" + projectId + 

"/agent/intents/"+intentid;

            var resp=client.GetIntent(intentname
                );
```

Where do i set the Intentview.Full value in the response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an extra parameter in GetIntent function call.

```
var resp=client.GetIntent(intentname,
 intent_view=dialogflow.enums.IntentView.INTENT_VIEW_FULL);
```

Now in C#, param name might be `IntentView` instead of `intent_view`, please check both.
Refer [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/get) for details about intent view.

Hope it helps.